# SpringMVC (Security) - 403 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a simple Java web application with SpringMVC. With security enabled, I cannot send a HTTP post request (from the index.jsp) to the server although I am already authenticated. POST request does work when the security isn't implemented. So I think it's a problem with my `SecurityConfig.java` code.Could you please help me with this? Thanks very much

Error Code :

```
HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden

Type Status Report

Message Forbidden

Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
```

This is my security configuration.

SecurityConfig.java

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Autowired
     public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("{noop}123456").roles("USER");

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .formLogin()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/index").hasRole("USER");

        }
    }
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

     <form action='@{/index}' method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">

     <td><textarea class="form-control" name="textForm">${text1}</textarea>   
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     <textarea name="textFin">${textFinal}</textarea></td>
     </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add 
`http.csrf().disable();` to configure method.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/index").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();

}
```

You are confusing `jsp` with `thymleaf`. Edit the `jsp file` to:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

     <form:form action="/index" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">

     <td><textarea class="form-control" name="textForm">${text1}</textarea>   
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     <textarea name="textFin">${textFinal}</textarea></td>
     </form:form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

The `UserDetailService` bean that you have provided didn't work for me. I had to change it like this:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    // ensure the passwords are encoded properly
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    manager.createUser(users.username("me").password("me").roles("USER").build());
    return manager;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply. Sorry for the delay. I got the code working by adding `http..csrf().disable();`

Comment: Could you please add that to your reply. So I can mark it as correct answer?

Comment: Thanks very much for response and clearing up my confusion with jsp page and also telling me another way to authenticate users.

Answer (score 1):

When we enable web security, for every form submitted, we need to send the _crsf(cross-site request forgery) token which is generated randomly base on the user's session.

If we don't want to use this token, we can disable it by calling `.csrf().disable()`

```
      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
         .formLogin()
         .and()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/index").hasRole("USER")
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/index").hasRole("USER")
         .and()
         .csrf().disable();

      }
```

But, in the real world, the token is preferred for security purposes. There are 2 approaches to generate the token.

- Approach 1: Generating token automatically by form tag `<form:form>`. Spring MVC will help us generated the token behind the scenes.
  use taglib:

```
     <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

and modify `<form action='@{/index}' method="POST">` to:

```
     <form:form action='@{/index}' method="POST">
          // our html code
     </form:form>
```

- Approach 2: Generating token manually by adding the hidden field.
  Before the close form tag `</form>`, add the following code.

```
     <form action='@{/index}' method="POST">
          // our html code 
          ...
          <input type="hidden" name="_csrf.parameterName" value="_csrf.token" />
     </form>
```